# Why with this css the background-color attribute doesn't work?

Tags: css, cross-browser, background-color

```
<body> 
    <div> 
        <div id="ROOT" > 
            <div id="ROOT_0" > 
                header  
            </div> 

            <div id="ROOT_1" > 
                main
            </div

            <div id="ROOT_2" > 
                footer
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</body> 

html {height:101%;}
body {background:#FFFFFF;}

#ROOT{ background-color:#666666; width:980px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}    
#ROOT_0{background-color:#FF9933; width:970px; text-align:center; float:left; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;}    
#ROOT_1{width:980px; text-align:center; float:left;}    
#ROOT_2{background-color:#FF9933; width:970px; text-align:center; float:left; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;}
```

IE get the right background. If i try on Chrome or firefox they don't get the background. Why? Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floated elements don't influence the height of their container. You are experiencing a bug in IE because you are not triggering Standards mode is a reasonably modern Doctype.

See [complex spiral](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/) for an explanation as to why things work this way and [Ed Elliot's blog](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59) for a number of better ways to count floats in the height.

Comment: uhm. If i write float:left; on #ROOT i can see that background change. But the main div go to the left, and is not more centered :(

Comment: So don't float the root! There are other approaches, you picked the 4th in the list at Ed's blog. I'd generally use the overflow method myself.

Comment: oh yeah!! overflow:auto works :) I'll use this, i don't care about IE for mac :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign height to the divs.